# How to create navigation in a Xamarin.iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm used to working with **Xamarin.Forms**. I create a Page in XAML or C# and navigate to it. But now it's my first time trying to create an iOS app that's not **Xamarin.Forms**. I'm doing it from Visual Studio on a Windows PC (connected to a Mac, of course). I've figured out that the `ViewController` is something like a **Xamarin.Forms** `Page`. But how do I create another page and tell the app to navigate to it? Do I create another `UIViewController`? And if so, how do I tell one to navigate to another?

All I've found are tutorials that use other IDEs. How do I do it in Visual Studio not "for Mac"?

Also, it seems that one way (the only way?) is to use something called a storyboard. However, in VS when clicking on a storyboard in solution explorer it starts "connecting to mac" (which it's already connected to) and there's a progress bar that just goes on and on. It never loads. So if there's a different way without a storyboard, that would be better.

Comment: PresentViewController : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontroller.presentviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Comment: @SushiHangover So I create a new class that inherits UIViewController (in solution explorer) and then do `vc1.PresentViewController(vc2...)`?

Comment: Yes, that is it. (of course if you are using a storyboard, you can instance the VC from there and then present/segue it, but in a non-storyboard way, that is all that is needed)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. You can transform that into an answer. And if there's a way to do the same thing but to _replace_ the original, that'd be welcome. Because this one seems to place the new one _over_ the first one. But even if there isn't, I can simply have an empty one and put everything on it. Thanks!

Comment: @SushiHangover This doesn't work. a) It doesn't cover the whole screen to the top. b) I can drag it down to make it disappear. I also tried `ShowViewController` with the same results.

Comment: @ispiro Hi ,have you solved it ? You can show screenshot if other problems .

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I create another page and tell the app to navigate to it? Do I create another UIViewController? And if so, how do I tell one to navigate to another?

You can create it as follow :

*Right* *click Xamarin IOS Project* **- >** *Add* **- >** *New Item* **- >** *User Interface* (UIViewController Class / ViewController With StoryBorad )

[image]

> All I've found are tutorials that use other IDEs. How do I do it in Visual Studio not "for Mac"?

Here is the official document about [Walkthrough on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios-multiscreen/hello-ios-multiscreen-quickstart?pivots=windows#requirements) however about using storyboard .And there is a sample project below it.

> So if there's a different way without a storyboard, that would be better.

If ViewController not exist in StoryBoard, then you can navigate to this Controller without StoryBoard .

```
this.PresentViewController(new UIViewControllerSecond(), true, null);
```

Else if StoryBoard contain the other ViewControllers , you also can use C# to navigate to next View.

```
SecondController secondController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondController ") as SecondController ;
if (secondController != null)
{
    this.PushViewController(secondController , true);
}
```

By the way , if Setting Root View Controller as `NavigationController` , use `this.NavigationController.PushViewController(...)` to navigate.