# How to connect multiple UIViewControllers without StoryBoard (pure code)? Xamarin.iOS native

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have multiple UIViewControllers, but I can't connect them through buttons. One of them must be an UINavigationController because I need the "back" button. Is it easier for this view being an UIViewController and I add a button manually to "go back"?

I am not using `storyboard/swift/objective-c`, it's `xamarin.ios` native

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087254/how-to-create-navigation-in-a-xamarin-ios-app

Comment: Thank you. I swear that I've searched and I didn't find any useful post. Should I delete the question?

Comment: One question when I do this:  this.PresentViewController(new UIViewControllerSecond(), true, null); the other view is in background. is there anyway for this view to disappear and the current UIViewController be in total charge?

Comment: The view which in background will not disappear .

Comment: The only way is to set that view as a RootController right ?

Comment: Yes , you are right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memyselfandi, There's a lot of different concepts to understand, and you can place a breakpoint to see the structure of your rootViewController. In order to get the RootViewController anywhere in your app, you can do this:

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
var rootVC = appDelegate.Window.RootViewController;
```

There's two way of adding a ViewController if your RootViewController does not have a UINavigationController:

1. You can only show your UIViewController through a PresentViewController from inside that RootViewController, so it appears as a modal and the other view can be seen in the background. This, as you already know, is simply done like this

```
PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
```

2. Or you can replace that RootViewController with a UINavigationController that contains your new UIViewController. And then just keep pushing things on to the NavigationController stack. This will prevent the other views to stay in the background.

```
var navController = new UINavigationController(vc); 
// where, vc is the ViewController you want to replace the existing one with.
// Eg: think of situations where you login a user.
rootVC = navController;
```

---

Bonus: It gets a little more complicated when you have viewControllers on top of other viewControllers stacked up in weird ways, so you can pass your viewController through something like this:

```
public static void Push(UIViewController vc)
{
    // to get the RootViewController, we have to get it from the AppDelegate
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    var rootVC = appDelegate.Window.RootViewController;

    // If you want to push to a ModalViewController which consists of a NavigationController
    if (rootVC.PresentedViewController != null && rootVC.PresentedViewController.NavigationController != null)
        rootVC.PresentedViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);

    // If there already is a NavigationController, you can do a simple push
    else if (rootVC.NavigationController != null)
        rootVC.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);

    // If the NavigationController exists in a TabBar, we have to push on that
    else if (rootVC != null
        && rootVC is UITabBarController tabbarController
        && tabbarController.SelectedViewController is UINavigationController navigationController)
        navigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);

    // If all else fails, present the ViewController as a modal
    else if (rootVC != null)
        rootVC.PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to understand. I was trying to make it as clear as I could. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Yes! You were very clear! Thank you so much!! You answered just what I needed to know! Thank you so muchhh again! I have another question, if you don't mind: if I used an UINavigationController instead of using ViewControllers i could just create UIViews for example right? And then push? Where would I create this NavigationController? In the AppDelegate?

Comment: No problem. UIViews cant be added directly, they have to be added to a UIViewController. UIViews are like controls/views/components that need to be added to Pages/ViewControllers. The UINavigationController is like a container of UIViewControllers