# display ViewController from Native forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to display native controller IOS from Xamarin.forms I have tried this

```
 UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
 UIViewController vc = window.RootViewController;

RGLDocReader.Shared.ShowScanner(vc, HandleRGLDocumentReaderCompletion);
```

this
[How to create navigation in a Xamarin.iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087254/how-to-create-navigation-in-a-xamarin-ios-app)

followed this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ios-code-only?tabs=macos

the tutorial works fine, however I need to use view controller in the method as that is specified and once I pass view controller I get null

Comment: You could add the native control on the xaml or ContentPage directly . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/code

Comment: so there is no way to create UIViewController and go there from Xamarin.forms?

Comment: I even created controller but I am still getting null reference

Answer (score 0):

Actually , it is not a good design to navigate to a native controller in Forms . But if you do want to implement it , you could use **DependencyService** .

#### in Forms

Create the interface

```
public  interface IOpenNativeView
{
   void OpenNativeView();
}
```

#### in iOS project

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenNativeView))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class OpenNativeView : IOpenNativeView
    {
        void IOpenNativeView.OpenNativeView()
        {
            var CurrentViewController = topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().RootViewController);
            CurrentViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(YourViewController,true);
        }

        UIViewController topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
        {
            if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                UITabBarController tabBarController = (UITabBarController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.SelectedViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                UINavigationController navigationController = (UINavigationController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.VisibleViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                UIViewController presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
            }
            else
            {
                return rootViewController;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the ContentPage you can invoke the following line when you want to open the ViewController

```
DependencyService.Get<IOpenNativeView>().OpenNativeView();
```

Comment: so what would be a good design? I need to pass the view controller to the method so that's why I have to do it

Comment: Why don't pass the native ContentPage ?

Comment: the method accepts only UiViewController its api done only for IOS

Comment: In this case you can use my solution .

Comment: I will have a look later

Comment: Sorry, not yet, I am atm working on driod part, that should be done today so I will try it later. Thank you for support